# Call a libsodium function with callback value

Tags: node.js, function, callback, libsodium

I try to hash and store a password into a database.
So I use libsodium with crypto_pwhash into a node app.
I create a function, export it, but I can not received the hash password.

Here is my code :
sodium.js

```
libsodium = require('libsodium-wrappers-sumo');
 (async() => {
await libsodium.ready;
const sodium = libsodium;

module.exports.password_hash = function(password, res){
var hashed_password = [sodium.crypto_pwhash_STRBYTES];
 if (sodium.crypto_pwhash_str ( sodium.crypto_pwhash_MEMLIMIT_SENSITIVE) != 0){
   /* out of memory */
}
   return res(hashed_password);
}
/*if (sodium.crypto_pwhash_str_verify
(hashed_password, PASSWORD, strlen(PASSWORD)) != 0) {
/* wrong password */
//}
})();
```

app.js

```
sodium.password_hash("test", function(res){
        console.log(res);  
     });
```

The error message is : unsupported input type for password.

I don't understand what is wrong

Update: i updade my code,
now the message error is : When defined, the output format must be a string
I think it is an issue with the array

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are doing in `sodium.js` because it looks like you are missing some brackets. Can you edit this so it's valid js?

Comment: I update my post, but there are only few more lines.

Comment: You need to give the password to the function supposed to hash it...

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 0):

sodium.crypto_pwhash_str return the hash password into a string, there is no need the first parameters